# Google Admin SDK: Get a list of groups that a user belongs to

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I see that it is possible to list all members that belong to a specific group, as documented here:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#get_all_members

But is it possible to get a list of groups that a user belongs to? I was hoping that Users.get would contain this information, or the Members API would have something similar, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I've found the solution in the Developer Guide, although it does not exist in the API documentation!!

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions to use the Admin API will work - but access to that API requires admin permissions. I've used a service account in the past, but that's not a great practice.

If you just want to make an API call to get a users's groups using the user's oauth token, you can use the Cloud Identity API - specifically groups.membership.searchTransitiveGroups: https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/searchTransitiveGroups

Here is some Ruby code to help explain:

```rb
token = # oauth token
email = # email address of authenticated user
url = "https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1/groups/-/memberships:searchTransitiveGroups"
params =  { query: "member_key_id == '#{email}' && 'cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum' in labels" }
headers = { Authorization: "Bearer #{token}" }
response = Faraday.get(url, params, headers)
group_list = JSON.parse(response.body).dig('memberships').map{|m| m.dig('groupKey','id')}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using the google admin sdk api.

[groups.list()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.groups.html)

[groups.list() with details](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.groups.html#list)

For example if you want to do it using the python sdk, you can use the following

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
import os.path
import csv
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
### https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing
### https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group']


"""
########################################################################################################################################################
# Logging level set for the script
# https://realpython.com/python-logging/
########################################################################################################################################################
"""
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class GSuite_management(object):
  """
  ########################################################################################################################################################
  # GSuite_management CLASS
  #  --> This class will have methods to manage the memebers of organization using Gsuite Admin SDK
  ########################################################################################################################################################
  """

  service = None

  def __init__(self):
      """
      GSuite_management Constrouctor
      """
      creds = None
      # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
      # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
      # time.
      if os.path.exists('token.json'):
          creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
      # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
      if not creds or not creds.valid:
          if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
              creds.refresh(Request())
          else:
              flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                  'credentials.json', SCOPES)
              creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
          # Save the credentials for the next run
          with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
              token.write(creds.to_json())  
      self.service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)          

  def list_all_groups_a_user_is_a_part_of(self, userEmail):
    """
    This method will list all the groups a user is a part of and return them as a list
    """
    listOfEmailGroups=[]
    try:
      results = self.service.groups().list(domain="yourdomain.com",userKey=userEmail, maxResults=400).execute()
      logging.debug(results)
      groups = results.get('groups', [])
      if not groups:
          print('No groups in the domain.')
      else:
          for group in groups:
            logging.info(u'{0} {1} {2}'.format(group['email'],group['name'], group['directMembersCount']))
            listOfEmailGroups.append(group['email'])
    except Exception as e:
      logging.error("Exiting!!!")
      SystemExit(e) 
    return listOfEmailGroups
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use any google-admin-sdk library like [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) to query groups of a particular user

This method is using `GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?userKey=userkey` endpoint linked in [jekennedy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24168011/2073920)

```js
/**
 * Retrieve all groups for a member
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {string} userEmail primary email of the user
 */
function listGroupsOfMember(auth, userEmail) {
  const admin = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth});
  admin.groups.list({
    userKey: userEmail,
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'email',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return console.error('The API returned an error:', err.message);
    }
    const groups = res.data.groups;
    if (groups.length) {
      console.log('Groups:');
      groups.forEach((group) => {
        console.log(group);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No groups found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Example usage:

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');


// acquire an authentication client using a service account
const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
  keyFile: path.join(__dirname, '../serviceaccount.json'),
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
  ],
});
// impersonate super admin
auth.subject = "admin@foo.me"

listGroupsOfMember(auth, "username@foo.me")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node.Js you can install this library:

`googleapis@105 @google-cloud/local-auth@2.1.0`

With this command for example:

`yarn add googleapis@105 @google-cloud/local-auth@2.1.0`

Then you can use a script like this one which uses a recursive function to find all groups to which a user belongs:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const path = require('path');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly'
];
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), '../client_secret_165820051388-0058a80cn1kgh4uk0ediif68t9m9n2ou.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');


/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file comptible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
  const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  const keys = JSON.parse(content);
  const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    type: 'authorized_user',
    client_id: key.client_id,
    client_secret: key.client_secret,
    refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
  });
  await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
  let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
  if (client) {
    return client;
  }
  client = await authenticate({
    scopes: SCOPES,
    keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  });
  if (client.credentials) {
    await saveCredentials(client);
  }
  return client;
}

/**
 * Lists all groups of a user recursively.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @oaram {string} userKey The user email
 */
async function listUsers(auth, userKey) {
  const service = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth});
  const accumulatedGroups = []
  const MAX_RESULTS = 5
  const orderBy = 'email'
  const res = await service.groups.list({
    userKey,
    maxResults: MAX_RESULTS,
    orderBy
  });

  const { groups, nextPageToken } = res.data
  let pageToken = nextPageToken
  if(!!groups) {
    accumulatedGroups.push(...groups)
  }
  while(!!pageToken) {
    const res = await service.groups.list({
      userKey,
      maxResults: MAX_RESULTS,
      pageToken,
      orderBy
    });
    const { groups, nextPageToken } = res.data
    pageToken = nextPageToken
    accumulatedGroups.push(...groups)
  }
  if(accumulatedGroups.length === 0) {
    return []
  }
  return [
    ...(await Promise.all(accumulatedGroups.map(g => g.email).map(e => listUsers(auth, e))))
      .flatMap(a => a),
    ...accumulatedGroups
  ]
}

authorize()
.then((client) => {
  console.log("Authentication saved")
  return listUsers(client, 'gil.fernandes@bkconnect.net')
}).then(groups => {
  groups.forEach(g => console.log(g.email))
}).catch(console.error)
```

This script will print out all emails of all groups to which a user with a specific email belongs. However make sure you have the right permissions for the user which created the Google App for which the Oauth credentials were generated. Otherwise you will get a 403 error.