# Google authentication and authorization with Golang

Tags: go, authentication, google-authentication

We have web app for internal usage and want to add auth with google.
So the authentication part was quite simple. I followed [this tutorial](https://skarlso.github.io/2016/06/12/google-signin-with-go/#getting-the-client)

But authorization part is not obvious for me. We have different roles in our system and want to give different roles to each google account and manage them there.
I want to use auth groups with scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/groups
So I have two questions, are the groups the right choice, I mean can we authenticate user by checking what group is he part of? Would be very thankful for any links for the authorization part

Comment: The easy approach is to store roles for an account in your own database. To authorize, use authenticated id to find roles and check for the required role.

Comment: @Zombo yep, we do it already. But the aim is to manage all this things in one place(i.e. google)

Comment: What do you need to manage through Google when user ids and roles are stored in your own database? The one place is your application.

Comment: @Zombo we want to get rid of auth process on our side because many processes are already through our google accounts

Answer (score -1):

I found this in python

[Google Admin SDK: Get a list of groups that a user belongs to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153960/google-admin-sdk-get-a-list-of-groups-that-a-user-belongs-to)

I haven't test it, but I think this is the way in go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    admin "google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {
    service, err := admin.NewService(context.Background(), option.WithCredentialsFile("cred.json"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    g, err := service.Groups.List().Customer("mail@example.com").Domain("example.com").Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(g)
}
```

source : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/main/admin/directory/v1/admin-gen.go